# Run as administrator under normal account windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp

We have the students logging in under their own accounts. however, they are not set up as administrators. However, this one application requires admin to run.

Is there a way to run only this application as admin without having to type in the password?

Comment: There are a few ways to "hack" it to be able to do this, but a better solution is if you know *why* the program needs administator access you might be able to make it so it does not need it anymore. For example if it needs to write to a folder that only administrators can write to then changing the permissions on that single folder to allow non-administrators write ccess.

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?q=run+program+as+admin

Comment: Congratulations, you're the 1,000,000th person to ask this question without searching first. You win a prize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT a secure solution, but you could use the `/savecred` option when using `runas`.

You can create a shortcut with a command similar to `runas /user:ComputerName\Administrator /savecred “C:\Path\To\Program.exe“`

A more in-depth tutorial can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/).